# Invertibility Proof for matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Suppose that A is a square matrix that satisfies $A^n=0$ for some positive integer n. Show that $I-A$ is invertible and $(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+A^2+...+A^{n-1}$.

Not sure how to start the problem.

Comment: You're given it's inverse so just do the multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint 1.* If the inverse $B$ exists, then it is defined uniquely by the property
$$
(I-A)B=I
$$
This problem gives you a candidate for $B$.

*Hint 2.* The polynomial $a^n-t^n$ factors as
$$
a^n-t^n=(a-t)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}t+\dotsb +at^{n-2}+t^{n-1}\right)
$$

Comment: But hint 1 doesn't tell if such a $B$ should exist. It gives the properties that if $B$ exists then it has that $(I-A)B=I$ but why should it exist?